# Trying to link two tables but getting all the information in one field

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables and im trying to get the name of a field that is linked with a code number and then ive got the other table where the code points to a score, I've managed to get them to print out but I want it to show like two columns no & name next to each other.

I've tried everything that I can think of but can't think how to structure the code.

```
SELECT no
 FROM take
  WHERE grade =  
   (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM take)
   UNION
    (SELECT name FROM delegate WHERE no = 2008);
```

I get this.

no

---

2008
Tom

Comment: Joins... LEFT join inner join, right join, cross join?...  table, sample data and expected results would help clarify your question.  change union to `cross join`.  This assumes each query will return only 1 record.

Comment: Or just put both queries in a select...

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  Here's a guide how to ask proper question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are ideal as the table structure seems to be faulty here... but maybe I don't understand the question yet..

```
SELECT no FROM take WHERE grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM take) 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT name FROM delegate WHERE no = 2008);

SELECT (SELECT no FROM take WHERE grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM take))
     , (SELECT name FROM delegate WHERE no = 2008);
```